# how to remove an asmx endpoint?

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404, asmx, http-status-code-405

I had a webservice .asmx endpoint that was deleted from the (IIS 7) website some time ago. There are still thousands of old software clients calling it so the server is continually generating full page **404** error responses and wasting bandwidth.

What I want to do is return an empty response - so I tried adding a rewrite rule to the web.config file to an empty, "removed" response but then the server returns another full **405** error page with

"The request sent to the Web server used an HTTP verb that is not allowed by the module configured to handle the request."

- how can I return an empty response to a missing asmx web service request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've done it by using a rewrite rule with action type "AbortRequest" - I then get a 502 error but that seems to be coming from the web browser and not the server.